# YouCompleteMe error: Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

Installed YouCompleteMe (./install.py --tern-complete --clang-complete) for vim and have an error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
  File "/Users/khotey/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/setup.py", line 37, in SetUpSystemPaths
    from ycmd import server_utils as su
  File "/Users/khotey/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/python/ycm/../../third_party/ycmd/ycmd/server_utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
YouCompleteMe unavailable: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem is Vim did not use the suitable Python version.

I solved it on my Mac by:

```
brew unlink python
brew link python
```

[Discussion in ycm issue.](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2218#issuecomment-249386057)

Comment: Funnily enough, that worked for me too. It happily installs with the mac version of python. Make sure that you remember to relink or reinstall (if you uninstalled) the brew version of python.